# Shell Script - Skipping over files to process

Tags: linux, docker, shell

I am trying to process multiple files present in a folder. My requirement is to process ALL the files but at max 15 in parallel. I wrote the below script to achieve the same. However, this isn't working as expected.

This script is processing all the files in the firs iteration (i.e. 15 in this case) but once the first 15 are done, it's processing alternate files. Thus if a folder has say 27 files, it's processing all the first 15 and then 6 of the remaining 12.

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

```
# Path to the folder containing the files
INPUT_FILES_FOLDER="/mnt/data/INPUT"
OUTPUT_FILES_FOLDER="/mnt/data/OUTPUT"

# Path to the Docker image
DOCKER_IMAGE="your_docker_image"

# Number of parallel instances of Docker to run
MAX_PARALLEL=15

# Counter for the number of parallel instances
CURRENT_PARALLEL=0

# Function to process files
process_files() {
    for file in "$INPUT_FILES_FOLDER"/*; do
    input_file=`basename $file` 
    output_file="PROCESSED_${input_file}"

    input_folder_file="/data/INPUT/${input_file}"
    output_folder_file="/data/OUTPUT/${output_file}"

    echo "Input File: $input_file"
    echo "Output File: $output_file"

    echo "Input Folder + File: $input_folder_file"
    echo "Output Folder + File: $output_folder_file"


        # Check if the current number of parallel instances is less than the maximum allowed
        if [ "$CURRENT_PARALLEL" -lt "$MAX_PARALLEL" ]; then
            # Increment the counter for the number of parallel instances
            ((CURRENT_PARALLEL++))
            
            # Run Docker container in the background, passing the file as input
        # docker run hello-world
        docker run --rm -v /mnt/data/:/data my-docker-image:v5.1.0 -i $input_folder_file -o $output_folder_file &
            
            # Print a message indicating the file is being processed
            # echo "Processing $file"
        else
            # If the maximum number of parallel instances is reached, wait for one to finish
            wait -n && ((CURRENT_PARALLEL--))
        fi
    done
    
    # Wait for all remaining Docker instances to finish
    wait
}

# Call the function to process files
process_files

I am trying to process multiple files present in a folder. My requirement is to process ALL the files but at max 15 in parallel. I wrote the below script to achieve the same. However, this isn't working as expected.

This script is processing all the files in the firs iteration (i.e. 15 in this case) but once the first 15 are done, it's processing alternate files. Thus if a folder has say 27 files, it's processing all the first 15 and then 6 of the remaining 12. 

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the inner loop.  Writing this out in pseudocode, your script is basically doing:

```
For each file:
  If there are fewer containers running then the maximum:
    Increment the counter
    Start a new container for the file
  Otherwise:
    Wait for a container to finish
```

Notice that in the `else` case, you do not `docker run` a container.  You wait for a previous container to exit, but then you don't do anything for the current file.

You should be able to restructure this to `wait` for a container to finish if you're at the limit, then start a new container outside the conditional.

```bash
for file in "$INPUT_FILES_FOLDER"/*; do
  # ... set up variables ...
  if [ "$CURRENT_PARALLEL" -ge "$MAX_PARALLEL" ]; then
    wait -n
    CURRENT_PARALLEL=$((CURRENT_PARALLEL - 1))
  fi
  CURRENT_PARALLEL=$((CURRENT_PARALLEL + 1))
  docker run --rm -v /mnt/data/:/data my-docker-image:v5.1.0 -i "$input_folder_file" -o "$output_folder_file" &
done
```

Comment: David, This works flawlessly. Thanks!